# SQL - Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: sql

I'm trying to use a functions on the `SQL SSMS2014` and I get the error on the title.

I can create new tables and databases no problem if i do it with a new query, but afterwards i can't edit or use the design function without getting that error on any of the databases that i have.

Most of the similar errors i found were related to connection to the database, but none of the fixes on those worked for me.

Comment: Can you share repro steps with details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the error message you are getting is:

> *the backend version is not supported to design database diagrams or tables*

Solution:

This is commonly reported as an error due to using the wrong version of SMSS. Use the version designed for your database version. You can use the command select @@version to check which version of sql server you are actually using. This version is reported in a way that is easier to interpret than than shown in the Help About in SMSS.

Using a newer version of SMSS than your database is generally error free, i.e. backward compatible.

Comment: Oh thank you, that worked out. I just changed changed laptops and didnt' notice that it had another SMSS version. Worked like a charm